Testing ksp generated internal classes
We recently migrated room from KAPT to KSP.
When kotlin code generation setting is on
extensions.configure<KspExtension> {
    arg("room.generateKotlin", "true")
}

The AutoMigration classes are generated as internal classes in the build/generated/ksp folder.
Unfortunately, this breaks the existing Unit tests as the Automigration implementations are not accessible as the KSP generates the classes as internal classes.
I could circumvent the issue with the
@file:Suppress("invisible_reference", "invisible_member")

declaration at the top of the file. But it is clearly a hack and unsafe and a feature that is likely to be retired soon.

Is it possible to solve this from gradle sourceset in an android library module?
Is it possible to instruct room ksp to make the generated Automigration classes as public or add @VisibleForTesting annotation to them?

Has anyone found a clean solution to this problem?
My convention plugin looks like this:

class AndroidRoomKspConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            pluginManager.apply("androidx.room")
            pluginManager.apply("com.google.devtools.ksp")

            extensions.configure<KspExtension> {
                arg("room.generateKotlin", "true")
            }

            extensions.configure<RoomExtension> {
                // The schemas directory contains a schema file for each version of the Room database.
                // This is required to enable Room auto migrations.
                // See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/AutoMigration.
                schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
            }

            dependencies {
                add("implementation", libs.findLibrary("ksp-symbol-processing").get())
                add("api", libs.findBundle("room-api").get())
                add(
                    "androidTestImplementation",
                    libs.findLibrary("androidx-room-testing").get()
                )
                add(
                    "testImplementation",
                    libs.findLibrary("androidx-room-testing").get()
                )
                add("ksp", libs.findLibrary("room-compiler").get())
            }
        }
    }
}

versions:
kotlinVersion = "2.0.20"
roomVersion = "2.6.1"
kspVersion = "2.0.20-1.0.25"


It turns out that we don't have to specify the AutoMigration classes anymore in the runMigrationsAndValidate method. It is applied automatically to the database just like it is done in the real application database.
@get:Rule
    val helper: MigrationTestHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
        Database::class.java,
    )

...

@Test
fun testAutoMigration() {
db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true)
// verify
}

